# Table view cell enabling editing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview

How can I enable editing for the user to input information on a given table view cell? I want to be able to add a couple of static cells and allow the user to insert information on those specific cells[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijbyj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `textField` to the rows you want the user to be able to edit

```
var txtField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
cell.addSubview(textView)
```

Let´s say you want the user to be able to add text to cell 3.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if (indexPath.row == 3){
        var txtField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
        cell.addSubview(textView)
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Update**
To change the height of selected cells, use the code below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        return 300.0
    } else {
        return 45.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to make the text field bigger and wrap the text show in the this picture.

Comment: awesome that should do